# Developing with celery and docker

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, celery

I have noticed that developing with celery in container, something like this:

```
  celeryworker:
    build: .
    user: django
    command: celery -A project.celery worker -Q project -l DEBUG
    links:
     - redis
     - postgres
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: config.settings.celery
```

if I want to do some changes on some celery task, I have to completly rebuild the docker image in order to have the latest changes.

So I tried:

```
docker-compose -f celery.yml down
docker-compose -f celery.yml up
```

Nothing changed, then:

```
docker-compose -f celery.yml down
docker-compsoe -f celery.yml build
docker-compose -f celery.yml up
```

I have the new changes.

Is this the way to do it? seems very slow to me, all the time rebuilding the image, is then better have the local celery outsite docker containers?

Answer (score 2):

Mount your `.` (that is, your working copy) as a volume within the container you're developing in.

That way you're using the fresh code from your working directory without having to rebuild (unless, say, you're changing dependencies or something else that requires a rebuild).

The idea is [explained here by Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-development-with-docker-compose), emphasis mine:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    env_file: .env
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./webapp:/opt/webapp  # <--- Whatever code your Celery workers need should be here
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

Comment: I follow your instructions and work great, one question, how can I write/create new files from inside the celery container? for example, celery needs write down in a logfile, it gives me permission denied, if I open a shell inside the celery container the userid and groupid looks like 1000:1000